# Are implicit casting and explicit casting has the same performance?

Tags: c#, interface, casting

Taken example from w3school:

```
int myInt = 9;
double myDouble = myInt;       // Automatic casting: int to double

Console.WriteLine(myInt);      // Outputs 9
Console.WriteLine(myDouble);   // Outputs 9
```

and

```
double myDouble = 9.78;
int myInt = (int) myDouble;    // Manual casting: double to int

Console.WriteLine(myDouble);   // Outputs 9.78
Console.WriteLine(myInt);      // Outputs 9
```

does explicit casting add extra overhead, especially for large number/array of numbers? or it is same as implicit casting?

I had to ask this for academic reason, and also would like to explicitly casting my objects and interfaces everywhere to add clarity on code base.

**Edit** :

add animal example:

```
IAnimal animal = (IAnimal) dog;
IAnimal animal = dog;
```

Comment: Implicit vs. explicit is a syntactical difference. Either way, it's happening; the IL that it generates is the same. There's no difference in processing, no additional overhead for one or the other.

Comment: If you place explicit casts in your code where implicit casts are possible, Visual Studio 2019 will dim the cast and give you a code fix to remove the unnecessary cast. Implicit casts are there to make your life easier.

Comment: I see, so it's more like syntactic sugar, how about interfaces? Does it still generate the same code on IL? for example animal above

Comment: Yes. If the conversion is implicit, it doesn't matter if it's an interface or a base class, it's the same. When a value type is implicitly converted to an interface, it has to box the value first, regardless of whether it's an implicit or explicit cast. Same with user-defined implicit cast operaters, it still has to call the operator's `op_Implicit` method.

Comment: You're going about this wrong. You don't get well performing code by learning a billion separate rules and then always applying them. *When* you need well performing code, you set goals, write simple code that meets the requirements and then *measure* the code against the goals. Only if it doesn't meet the goals do you start digging into why it's not performing well and *then* you can actually try out alternatives and see a) if they make a difference and b) whether the difference is significant enough to make it now pass the goals.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you mean I should write on my academic essay that I don't get well performing code by learning a billion separate rules and then always applying them? The essay don't care about goals.. Have you tried writing computer science essay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does explicit casting add extra overhead, especially for large number/array of numbers? or it is same as implicit casting?

You can refer to [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgTARgLACgYGYAE9MGFMDeqmJmqAkORpgCID2ArgEYQCmmAgg8HbgIYBnYAAoAlBXJEUlcmAB2wTAFsAngEkFmALyYAnAG4JVAOzL1Cw9PIBfVBInV5igLJ85DPhH5CxEqTIATRhZ2VXpmNm09ADpjAA5LGRhTYSdRMOC2RJtUayA=) to see the differences under the hood in IL. As you can see, the logic is pretty same (except the types, of course, because you are using the different types)

```
.method public hidebysig 
instance float64 AutoCast () cil managed 
{
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldc.i4.s 9
    IL_0002: conv.r8
    IL_0003: ret
} // end of method C::AutoCast

.method public hidebysig 
instance int32 ManualCast () cil managed 
{
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldc.r8 9.78
    IL_0009: conv.i4
    IL_000a: ret
} // end of method C::ManualCast
```

Or even refer to ASM code

```
C.AutoCast()
    L0000: sub esp, 0x8
    L0003: vzeroupper
    L0006: vmovsd xmm0, qword [0x14540488]
    L000e: vmovsd [esp], xmm0
    L0013: fld qword [esp]
    L0016: add esp, 0x8
    L0019: ret

C.ManualCast()
    L0000: mov eax, 0x9
    L0005: ret
```

As you can see, cast `double` to `int` just moves value and return an integral part, `int` to `double` more complicated. As a result of that, you can see the different benchmark results.

[image]

Of course, it depends on used CLR and .NET version (there are a lot improvements in .NET Core and some hardware intrinsics were added as well). I've run it using .NET Core and CoreCLR, in .NET Framework you'll see the different results.

You can check the exact behavior on your environment with your code (at least because you've asked a question for academic reason)

Comment: Thank you Mr. Pavel, it looks like I can't get exact answer without SharpLab. I'm sorry Mr. Pavel, does this means for my question title, your answer is yes (same)?

Comment: For your example, cast from `double` to `int` and vise versa, the answer is seems to be "no", because there is some differences actually (depending on used .NET version, etc). For other cases the answer "it depends" :)